# How to work with xml and java (android)

Tags: java, android, xml

How do I make something in xml, and change the value of it in Java?

ex:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:editable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

Now how do I edit the text from being "Hello World" to something else in Java?

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you tried searching around for an answer to this ?

Comment: There are many, many sites available that provide tutorials for getting started with Android programming. Please refer to those first.

Comment: google.com will help you

Comment: I tried, I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basic knowledge of android man, you can find it on every tutorial.

This is how you can modify the text of a text view, in this case yours:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to first have an handle to the TextView widget

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Then set the text

```
tv.setText(...)
```